How to solve this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
I am running a hyperledger fabric network, it is deployed in a docker container.
When running the network, I am deploying a chaincode "fabcar" on the network, and this chaincode is a javascript file.
In the javascript file, I am including "snarkjs" library. So when I am including the library, and try to deploy it on the network, the status in Docker indicates that the container exited with a non-zero exit code, and if i check the docker logs of this container, I get this error.
So the chaincode originally works, until I add: const snarkjs = require("snarkjs");
and here the error started to appear.
I am using node v20.13.1 (I tried to change versions but still got this error)
npm 10.5.2
docker 25.0.0
Ubuntu 20.04
The error:
if(globalThis?.Blob) {
              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/src/node_modules/@iden3/binfileutils/build/main.cjs:5:20)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)


By default, when you deploy chaincode to Fabric, the chaincode is run in a Docker container created using the hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv image. The version of the image is related to the version of Fabric used. Certainly in recent Fabric version, a chaincode Docker image with the same major/minor version tag is used. This chaincode Docker image bundles a particular version of Node, which is used to run the chaincode. It seems that whatever version of Node is running the chaincode does not support more recent JavaScript language constructs, like ?..
From your stacktrace the error looks to occur on this line in the @iden3/binfileutils package. My guess is that it is actually failing due to this line in the ffjavascript package.
The fabcar sample on which you are basing your smart contract is very old. It might be that you are using an old version of Fabric, which might explain an outdated Node runtime. You could consider either:

Using the latest release of Fabric. At the time of writing, this is Fabric v2.5. The Node chaincode container for this version uses Node 18 and is looking to move to Node 20.
Running your chaincode as an external service. Here you run the chaincode process yourself in an environment of your choosing instead of having Fabric run it in a chaincode Docker container. The fabric-samples repository contains a working sample demonstrating this approach.

